# Magnetic force and frames of reference

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the next situation:

Suppose that I have a magnet that creates a quite uniform magnetic filed $\vec B$. In the vicinity of this magnet there is a particle with charge $q$ that is moving with velocity $\vec v$ in some direction.

This is, in the frame of reference of the magnet, the particle is moving with velocity $\vec v$ and therefore the particle experiences a force given by: $\vec F=q \, (\vec v \times \vec B)$. This would cause the path of the particle to curve around the magnetic field.

On the other hand, an observer situated in the particle would see the magnet moving with velocity $\vec v'=-\vec v$. How would this observer account for the movement of the magnet caused by the force $F'$?

I believe that the force $\vec F'$ is given by the relativistic transformation:
$$\vec F'=-\gamma \vec F$$
Knowing that the force is perpendicular to the velocity (this is if, for instance, the particle is moving along the $x$ axis, then the force is along the $y$ axis).

I am in the early stages of understanding relativistic mechanics so please forgive me is the question looks silly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something to think about: The observer on the particle is feeling an acceleration: he should have no doubt that he is moving relative to the magnet, not that the magnet is being accelerated. The person on the particle is not in an inertial frame of reference.

Comment: Do you mean: "How would this observer account for the movement of the particle caused by the force F′?"

Comment: @LarryHarson I mean the observer on the particle would see the magnet experience a force $F'$, then how would he account for it?

Comment: @Floris I thought about that, but I've come up with the book "Lectures on Physics" by Feynman in which he shows how the magnetic force exerted on a moving particle by a current in a wire can be seen as a purely electrostatic effect from the frame of reference of the particle. This would be a similar situation, I guess.

Comment: A current in a wire is not exactly the same as a particle moving freely in a circle... in the case of a straight wire there may be a force, but there is no acceleration. But that is not what you described in your question.

Comment: I mean a particle that is next to a wire, which freely moves parallel to it. This particle experiences a Force that is, in the frame of reference of the wire, caused by a magnetic field and, from the frame of reference of the particle, by an electric field.

Comment: When you transform force, you can't switch what it acts upon between frames; it has to refer to the same object it's acting upon in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an electric component to the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force):

$$\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v\times\vec B)$$

In the frame of the particle where its velocity is zero, the force acting on the stationary particle would be interpreted as being electric, since the magnetic field $\vec {B'}$ only acts on moving charge, and is given by:

$$\vec {F'}= q'\vec {E'}$$

In your example, we can take $\vec v$ along $x$ and $\vec B$ along $z$ giving a $\vec {F_y'}$ along $-y'$ so that the forces transform as :

$$\vec {F_y'} = \gamma\vec F_y,\quad q'\vec E_y'= \gamma q \vec v\times \vec B_z$$

And this is consistent with how the fields should [transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#The_E_and_B_fields), remembering that charge is a relativistic invariant where $q = q'$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes total sense! Thanks for the clarification on how the transformations should be. Now, how would you explain this relativistic phenomena? I mean, why is there an electric field, where does it come from? I believe this would have to do with the internal structure of the magnet, i.e., how the particles in the magnet create  the magnetic field.

Comment: @Francisco The modern understanding of electric fields and magnetic fields is that they are not distinct entities. That is, electric fields and magnetic fields are exactly the same thing seen from different viewpoints (inertial frames, if you want to get technical). That's why we call call it the electromagnetic field when talking about fundamental physics. It was Einstein who figured out how to write Maxwell's equations using a single unified force field.